# Show that the curvature of the curve is given by $|{\bf H}|^{−3}|{\bf H}×({\bf H·∇}){\bf H}|$.

Tags: vector-analysis, curvature

> The tangent vector at each point on a curve is parallel to a
>   non-vanishing vector field ${\bf H}({\bf x})$. Show that the curvature
>   of the curve is given by $|{\bf H}|^{−3}|{\bf H}×({\bf H·∇}){\bf H}|$.

I've never tackled a question like this and I'm struggling a bit, so I think it would help to see one worked example.

I have all the definitions in front of me, but they're not helping much. I can't see any way of doing it that doesn't require at some point differentiation with respect to $s$ (the arclength) and I don't know how we could get anything into that form.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: **Hint** There is an alternate formula for curvature

$$\kappa = \frac{|\vec{r}'(t) \times \vec{r}''(t)|}{|\vec{r}'(t)|^3}$$

where 

$$\mathbf{x}(t) = \vec{r}(t) = \langle x(t), y(t), z(t) \rangle$$

in your notation. From here use the above formula (keeping in mind your condition about $\vec{H}(\mathbf{x})$ and keep track of your partials when using the chain rule. If you need more help, I can post a full solution later

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. I'll have a go and let you know

Comment: This is a little embarrassing, but I'm still having issues. Surely ${\bf H}={\bf r}'(t)$ as they're both tangent. This leaves us to show that $({\bf H \cdot \nabla}){\bf H}={\bf r}''(t)={\bf H}'(t)$. Let ${\bf H}=(H_1(x,y),H_2(x,y))$ then I get ${\bf H}'(t)=({\frac {\partial H_1}{\partial x} \frac {dx}{dt}+\frac {\partial H_1}{\partial y} \frac {dy}{dt},\frac {\partial H_2}{\partial x} \frac {dx}{dt}+\frac {\partial H_2}{\partial y} \frac {dy}{dt})$ but $({\bf H \cdot \nabla}){\bf H} has $H_1$ in place of any $\frac {dx}{dt}$ and similar for $H_2$ and $y$. Is my approach wrong, or an error?

Comment: Oh god, what have I done? Anyways, I'm still having issues so anything else would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Uh you should reformat the previous comment. Also @kobe basically did it out

Answer (score 2):

Let $c(t)$ be the curve. For some non-vanishing scalar field $\lambda$, $c'(t) = \lambda(c(t))\mathbf{H}(c(t))$. By the product rule, $$c''(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(\lambda(c(t)))\, \mathbf{H}(c(t)) + \lambda(c(t))\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{H}(c(t)))$$ By the chain rule, $$\frac{d}{dt}(\lambda(c(t)) = \nabla \lambda(c(t))\cdot c'(t) = \nabla \lambda(c(t)) \cdot\lambda(c(t))\mathbf{H}(c(t)) = \lambda(c(t))[\nabla \lambda\cdot \mathbf{H}](c(t))$$

and

\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{H}(c(t))) &= \langle c'(t)\cdot \nabla H^1(c(t)), c'(t)\cdot \nabla H^2(c(t)), c'(t)\cdot \nabla H^3(c(t))\rangle\\
&=\langle \lambda\mathbf{H}(c(t))\cdot \nabla H^1(c(t)), \lambda\mathbf{H}(c(t))\cdot \nabla H^2(c(t)), \lambda \mathbf{H}(c(t))\cdot \nabla H^3(c(t))\rangle\\
&=\lambda[(\mathbf{H}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{H}](c(t))
\end{align}

Consequently, $$c'\times c'' = \lambda \mathbf{H}\times(\lambda \mathbf{H}[\nabla \lambda \cdot \mathbf{H}] + \lambda^2[(\mathbf{H}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{H}]) = \lambda^3 [\mathbf{H}\times (\mathbf{H}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{H}]$$ and the curvature of the curve at a point $\mathbf{x} = c(t_0)$ is

$$\frac{\lvert c'(t_0)\times c''(t_0)\rvert}{\lvert c'(t_0)\rvert^3} = \frac{\lvert \lambda\rvert^3\lvert [\mathbf{H}\times (\mathbf{H}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{H}](\mathbf{x})\rvert}{\lvert\lambda\rvert^3\lvert \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x})\rvert^3} = \lvert \mathbf{H}\rvert^{-3}\lvert \mathbf{H}\times(\mathbf{H}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{H}\rvert(\mathbf{x}) $$

Comment: I think you should assume that $c'(t) = \lambda(c(t)) \mathbf{H(c(t))}$ for full generality. You get an extra term in $c''(t)$, but it disappears when you take the cross product, so the bulk of the proof is the same

Comment: @J.Marx-Kuo yes, that's right. I'm making an edit.